# kanjis have 音読み{おんよみ}、訓読み{くんよみ}、and something like "人名読み{じんめいよみ}". But, what is the real term for "人名読み"?

Tags: kanji

sorry that I could not come-up with a better title...

The readings of the kanjis in a person's name, is theoretically arbitrary. But in reality, a kanji tends to have a set of maybe 3 or 4 probable readings when used in a name. For example: [伊](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E4%BC%8A), under the "**Japanese names**" header, has the following probable readings: "いと、これ、ただ、だ、よし". So, what is the official name for that set of readings?

a kanji has:
(-) 訓読み
(-) 音読み
(-) ??? 読み <--- set of the most frequently used readings in people's names.

what is the set name?

Comment: I wouldn't set up a classification solely for readings in people's names. Most of these can be classified as _kun_; they are just nonstandard and may not appear in dictionary as _kun_ readings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [名乗]{なの}り

Comment: I always wondered where that term came from.  I've seen it in Jim Breen's KANJIDIC and other English language resources, but the 漢和辞典 that I have don't seem to use the term 「名乗り読み」.  Is it used by other dictionaries or official documents?

Comment: @snailplane: 大辞泉 seems to use it (simply as 名のり) -- http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154866/m1u/%E6%9D%B1/

Comment: @Hyperworm Ooh, thanks!  That's very interesting.  It seems that the 学研 dictionaries use 名づけ (both my smaller 大きな字の常用漢和辞典 and [the larger 漢字源](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13296369#13296369)), while 新漢語林 seems to mark them 名前.